# Rotate Armature

Tags: rigging, armature

I am trying to rig this f16, and I am failing to rotate the axis of rotation (I want it to be the X). I am trying to make the slats on the front of the wing go down, but have no idea how.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the transform orientation using the menu located in the middle of the header near the top of the screen. If none of those orientations are aligned the way you want to, you can create a new orientation using the + button. That will create an orientation based upon the selected object.

[image: Transform Orientation Menu]